# Which aspects of evolutionary biology are most relevant to medical practice?

Tags: evolution, medicine

I'm not pretty much sure if this question suites this forum. But I think its important.

In what aspects evolutionary biology can be seen to be very helpful in medical curricula?

Clearly infection and drug resistance seems to be relevant, also pointed are Cancer evolution.

Are there some interesting output on Neurology in particular?

Comment: [wikipedia > Evolutionary medicine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_medicine)

Comment: ah thanks, I never heard of this term in all of my medical life. I see that there is a whole discipline addressing this question, that is actually never even been mentioned in medical schools unfortunately.

Comment: I see that there is evolutionary neuroscience as well. Good!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_neuroscience